# solaR timestamp for radiation on a tilted surface

Tags: r, time-series

I am trying to use the R package *solaR* to calculate irradiance on a tilted plane given measured irradiance on the horizontal plane. I can get the code to work, but the final output timestamp does not make sense.

Data for this code can be found [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/r06ya327jpghuiz/one_day_WSL_8.csv). It is one day's worth of measured irradiance (global horizontal -- ghz, direct normal -- dir, diffuse horizontal -- dhz, and outdoor temp ta) for Austin, TX. The timestamp is local 'CST6CDT' time. The data is for a clear day, so that maximum value of global horizontal (ghz) should roughly correspond with solar noon (the time that the sun crosses the local meridian).

My code is as follows:

```
library(solaR)

sol_data <- read.csv(file)

    # The data must be named a certain way.
names(sol_data) <- c('time', 'G0', 'B', 'D0', 'Ta')

    # The negatives are an artifact of the sensor and are set to 0.
sol_data$G0 <- ifelse(sol_data$G0 < 0, 0, sol_data$G0)
sol_data$B <- ifelse(sol_data$B < 0, 0, sol_data$B)
sol_data$D0 <- ifelse(sol_data$D0 < 0, 0, sol_data$D0)

# This calculates the beam incidence on the horizontal plane. 
sol_data$B0 <- sol_data$G0 - sol_data$D0
sol_data$B0 <- ifelse(sol_data$B0 < 0, 0, sol_data$B0)

    # This takes the data and assigns the timestamp to a certain format and timezone
idxLocal <- with(sol_data, as.POSIXct(time, format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', tz = 'CST6CDT'))
    # This converts the timestamp to solar time
idx <- local2Solar(idxLocal, lon = -97.7428)

    # Creates a zoo object needed to make the Meteo file for input
z <- zoo(sol_data[,c('G0', 'D0', 'B0', 'Ta')], idx)

    # local latitude
lat = 30.2669

    # Creates a Meteo file
My_Meteo <- zoo2Meteo(z, lat=lat)


# Finds the start and end date of the input file
start <- idx[1] 
end <- idx[length(idx)] 

    # Returns a base time for the calculations
BTd <- fBTd(mode = 'serie', year = '2013', start = start, end = end, format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    # Computes the movement of the sun/earth
sol <- calcSol(lat = 30.2669, BTd, sample = 'min')

# Creates a G0 file for solar rad on horizontal surface
compI <- calcG0(30.2669, modeRad = 'bdI', dataRad = My_Meteo, corr = 'none')
    # creates the angles for calculation of the rad on a tilted surface
angGen <- fTheta(sol = sol, beta = 0, alfa = 0)
    # Calculates the irradiance on a tilted surface
irad_tilt <- fInclin(compI, angGen)
```

When I use beta = 0, alfa = 0 (a flat plane) I should get roughly the same output as my input. However, when I search for the max value of global horizontal irradiance:

```
x <- which.max(irad_tilt$G) 
irad_tilt[x,]
```

I get it to return a max at 2013-05-05 10:43:01 and I cannot figure out what/why this time is as it is. It is not local time, that should be around 13:24. Local solar time should be around 12:00. UTC time should be around 18:24, and UTC solar time (if there is such a thing) should be 17:00...

I know this is obscure, but any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tested the code and data in my computer with correct
results. Let's reproduce the main steps with some graphical
outputs:

```
library(solaR)

sol_data <- read.csv('/tmp/one_day_WSL_8.csv')

## The data must be named a certain way.
names(sol_data) <- c('time', 'G0', 'B', 'D0', 'Ta')

## The negatives are an artifact of the sensor and are set to 0.
sol_data$G0 <- ifelse(sol_data$G0 < 0, 0, sol_data$G0)
sol_data$B <- ifelse(sol_data$B < 0, 0, sol_data$B)
sol_data$D0 <- ifelse(sol_data$D0 < 0, 0, sol_data$D0)

## This calculates the beam incidence on the horizontal plane.
sol_data$B0 <- sol_data$G0 - sol_data$D0
sol_data$B0 <- ifelse(sol_data$B0 < 0, 0, sol_data$B0)

## This takes the data and assigns the timestamp to a certain format and timezone
idxLocal <- with(sol_data, as.POSIXct(time, format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', tz = 'CST6CDT'))
```

The function `local2Solar` converts the time zone of a `POSIXct` object to the mean solar time and set its time zone to UTC as a synonym of mean solar time. It includes two corrections: the difference of longitudes between the location and the time zone, and the daylight saving time.

```
idx <- local2Solar(idxLocal, lon = -97.7428)

## Creates a zoo object needed to make the Meteo file for input
z <- zoo(sol_data[,c('G0', 'D0', 'B0', 'Ta')], idx)
```

Because your data belongs to a clear day and this time series uses
mean solar time, the maximum should be located around noon.

```
xyplot(z, type=c('l', 'g'))
```

[image: data with mean solar time]

Now we compute the sun geometry with `calcSol`. Here I am using a
different code from yours.

```
## local latitude
lat = 30.2669
## Computes the movement of the sun/earth
sol <- calcSol(lat, BTi=idx)

xyplot(as.zooI(sol), type=c('l', 'g'))
```

[image: sun geometry]

Next we calculate radiation on the horizontal surface.

```
g0 <- calcG0(lat, modeRad = 'bdI', dataRad = z, corr = 'none')

xyplot(as.zooI(g0), type=c('l', 'g'))
```

[image: horizontal irradiance]

Finally, with `calcGef` we obtain irradiance on a tilted surface:

```
gef <- calcGef(lat=lat, modeRad='bdI', dataRad=z)

xyplot(as.zooI(gef), type=c('l', 'g'))
```

[image: irradiance on the tilted plane]

I suspect that your problem is related with time zones defined in
your computer. Could you check these results?:

```
lonHH('America/Chicago')
## [1] -1.570796
lonHH('CDT6CST')
## [1] -1.570796

idxLocal1 <- as.POSIXct(sol_data$time, format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', tz = 'CST6CDT')
idxLocal2 <- as.POSIXct(sol_data$time, format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', tz = 'America/Chicago')

idxUTC1 <- as.POSIXct(format(idxLocal1, tz='UTC'), tz='UTC')
idxUTC2 <- as.POSIXct(format(idxLocal2, tz='UTC'), tz='UTC')

all.equal(idxUTC1, idxUTC2)
## [1] TRUE
```

Maybe these technical notes are useful for additional information on
this topic:

- [Ripley, B. D. and Hornik, K. (2001) Date-time classes. R News, 1/2, 8–11](http://www.r-project.org/doc/Rnews/Rnews_2001-2.pdf).
- [Gabor Grothendieck and Thomas Petzoldt (2004), Date and Time Classes in
  R, R News 4(1), 29-32](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/Rnews/Rnews_2004-1.pdf).

Besides, you should take a look at the information and examples of `help(timezone)`.

Comment: Thank you! There is one edit that I would need for the above code. Before the radiation is calculated on the horizontal or tilted plane, I think that z needs to be changed to a Meteo object: `z <- zoo2Meteo(z, lat=lat)` first.

Comment: I think my main problem was where our code deviated `sol <- calcSol(lat, BTi=idx)` I get the same results when checking the time zones defined on my computer with your last bit of code above. Thanks.

Comment: @user1813094 `solaR` 0.36 does not require the intermediate conversion from `zoo` to `Meteo` before using `calcG0` or `calcGef`. Try this code with the last version available at CRAN.

Answer (score 1):

thank you greatly for responding directly and for the great package. It turns out we had a wildly wrong interpretation of solar time. I am seeing a different possible issue that would not fit into the comments section.

When I run:

```
local2Solar(as.POSIXct("2013-07-07 13:36:00",tz="America/Chicago"),lon=-97.7428)
```

I get `"2013-07-07 12:05:01 UTC"`. According to NOAA, `"2013-07-07 13:36:00"` is solar noon for that day.

Just to confuse matter, when I run:

```
local2Solar(as.POSIXct("2013-06-07 13:30:00",tz="America/Chicago"),lon=-97.7428)
```

I get `"2013-06-07 11:59:01 UTC"`, so it appears to be very close. According to NOAA, `"2013-06-07 13:30:00"` is solar noon for that day.

If you were to run:

```
local2Solar(as.POSIXct("2013-01-07 12:37:27",tz="America/Chicago"),lon=-97.7428)
```

You would get `"2013-01-07 12:06:28 UTC"`. According to NOAA, `"2013-01-07 12:37:27""` is solar noon for that day.

I ran G. Master's equations separately from `solaR` and got: `"2013-06-07 13:29:30 CDT"` (the highest precision is each minute for this version) for the time with maximum incident power for the first case on `"2013-06-07"`.